# How to check if the unloaded route and the loading route are same in Iron router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In one of my Iron router route controller unload function I have some code segment to run. But I need to run those code if the unloaded route and the loading routes are different. How can I check this?

```
myRouteController = RouteController.extend({
    unload: function() {
        // This is called when you navigate to a new route
        Session.set('postId', null);
    }
})
```

I want to set the session to null if the current route and the new route are different.

Comment: Is this what you are asking, because it seems unusual --- If the browser (or user) navigates to a different URL at the same website, whether manually or because of a link, how can I reset the session object on that browser to null?

Comment: @Paul I am using the iron router to control my routes. I want to set the session if the current router and the loading routers are different

Comment: I don't think iron router triggers a path change if the same route is navigated to.